# How to format numbers in Apache Superset table chart when displaying raw records

Tags: apache-superset

I want to display some raw records (i.e. not aggregated) in a chart table.
I don't see a way to control number formats in this chart.
I have tried the following:

- When looking at the column definition in the dataset, the format field only applies in case of datetime.
- Also if I create metrics, I can only use them in aggreage table.
- Creating a calulated column doesn't help either.

As a result of this, here is the kind of table I get:
[image]

How should I proceed to solve this?

Comment: What version of Superset are you using? In newer version(I think from 0.38), in explore mode there is an option to show table as aggregated or raw records.

Comment: I am using version 1.0.1. But the point is that I don't want to aggregate. Well I guess I could aggregate based on id... but it seems like a hack.

Comment: This seems like a limitation. You should raise a feature request on github https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/new?assignees=&labels=%23enhancement&template=feature_request.md

Answer (score 0):

Use a calculated column and change it to a datatype with precision.

```
CAST(myRecord as double(10,2))
```